# If:true is not working properly in LWC, Can anyone please explain?

Tags: lightning-web-components

I am having issue with if:true statement. I am unable to print `Value 0` by using `if:true` statement and I dont know the reason exactly.

My requirement is to print `0 value` by using `if:true`

Here is the code below

```html
<template>

    <template if:true={value}>
        Value 0
    </template>

    <template if:true={value1}>
        Value 10
    </template>

</template>
```

JS file -

```js
import { LightningElement, track, api } from 'lwc';

export default class App extends LightningElement {

    @track value = 0;
    @track value1 = 10;
}
```

Here is the link for your [reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/KY2Tp8v1l/1/edit)

Here is below screenshot of Output : 
[image]

Comment: you should use `get` variable to show the value

Comment: value = 0 does not evaluate to something truthy, value1 = 10 however does. So, value is NOT true.

Answer (score 5):

The reason why `if:true={value}` equals `false` because `0` value is [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy). `if:true` directive expects boolean context, thus making type coercion. I'd recommend you to use `getters`. In your case, it can be looked like (if you expect the `value` property of `number` type):

```js
@track value = 0;

get hasValue() {
   return typeof value === 'number' && isFinite(value);
}
```

```html
<template if:true={hasValue}>
    {value}
</template>
```

Comment: Nice answer, this is also how [if value](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5515349/1023542) statement works in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Use Getter to return `true/false` whether a value is equal to 0 or not

playgroung : [link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/KY2Tp8v1l/5/edit)

HTML:

```
<template>
<template if:true={isTrue}>
    Value 0
</template>
<template if:true={value1}>
    Value 10
</template>
</template>
```

JS::

```
import { LightningElement, track, api } from 'lwc';

export default class App extends LightningElement {

    @track value = 0;
    @track value1 = 10;

    get isTrue(){
    return this.value == 0 ? true : false
   }
}
```

Comment: `return this.value == 0;` The `==` operator already returns a true/false value.